# Check is user inputs Black, Green or Red. C#

Tags: c#

I'm working on a program where I want my user to enter one of the following Colors (Red, Green or Black). But I am stuck.

What I have done so far is this

```
Console.Write("Color To Bet on: ");
string tempColor = Console.ReadLine();

while (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tempColor))
{
    Console.Write("The color can't be null.");
    tempColor = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
}
```

But how can I make sure my users puts in the color I want, I've tried fiddling around with string. Contains method but haven't had any success so far.

Comment: You could use `enum ValidColor { Black, Green, Red };` is this what you want? What kind of inputs that you want your user to be restricted to?

Comment: I just want my user to be restricted to enter, Green, Red or Black. Doesn't have to be capital letters that would be strange, but those 3 colors.

Comment: Ok, now you get plenty of answers. =)

Comment: isn't it better to show him a choice of possible color, rather than let him write the whole string?

Comment: @gsharp I agree. That's what I first suggested...

Comment: I want to point out that the fist time you read `tempColor` it lacks `ToLower`. Just saying >.>

Comment: @gsharp Yes, assuming though I would need to use forms. I'll try to stick with the console window until I get a better hang of the basics.

Comment: @FooBar no you don't need forms. You can do something like:

Press the number for your color
1: Red
2: Green
3: Blue

And you can generate this Menu Choice by reading out an enum or so (like Marcus solution)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can never have any control of what the user enters when you allow the users to provide free text. What you could do would be to provide a GUI with a radio button or list like structure from where the user *must* select.

In your case, the easiest way would be to declare an array of colours that the user can type, and each time, you compare it with what the user provided:

```
string[] allowedInput = new string[]{"black", "green", "red"};
Console.Write("Color To Bet on: ");
string tempColor = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();

while ((String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tempColor)) || (!allowedInput.Contains(tempColor)))
{
    Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Invalid color. Allowed colors are : {0}.", String.Join(", ", allowedInput)));
    tempColor = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the fast reply, easier than I thought.

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois: Yes sorry my bad, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: "The color can't be null." is not the appropiate message for when the color is not in the array. Also, there are no null or whitepsace in the array, so that check is redundant. [And I see you catched the missing `ToLower`]

Comment: Edit approved, just a minor detail, MS recommends that when you call static methods for the String class you use `String` not `string`.

Comment: @npinti ho, didn't knew that. Thanks for the information.

Answer (score 5):

You could declare an enum and use `Enum.TryParse`:

```
enum Color { Black, Green, Red };

Console.Write("Color To Bet on: ");
string tempColor = Console.ReadLine();
Color color;

// Enum.TryParse will try to parse the user's input
// and if it fails, it will return false and will ask from the user to 
// enter a valid color.
while (!Enum.TryParse(tempColor, out color))
{
    Console.Write("You should peak one color from Black, Green and Red.");
    tempColor = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Comment: Yup, it should be something like this. Voted up.

Comment: You have the colors both in the message and on the enum, you may update the enum and forget to upade the message.

Comment: BLACK and black will not match.

Comment: Exactly, BLACK and black will not match.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this.

```
   var colorList = new List<string>(){"red","black","green"};
            Console.Write("Color To Bet on: ");
            string tempColor;
            bool isValid =false;
            do
            {
                tempColor = Console.ReadLine();
                isValid = colorList.Any(item => item == tempColor);
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid Color i.e" + string.Join(",",colorList.ToArray()));

            }while(!isValid);
```

Answer (score 1):

Dummy proofed version:

```
    public static ConsoleColor ReadColor()
    {
        string tmp = tmp = Console.ReadLine().Trim().ToLower();
        switch (tmp)
        {
            case "red": return ConsoleColor.Red;
            case "green": return ConsoleColor.Green;
            case "black": return ConsoleColor.Black;
            default:
                throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid input - " + tmp);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Extending Ian's comment:

You should create `enum` of valid colors and parse user input with `Enum.TryParse`

sample code

```
public enum MyColor
{
    Black,
    Green,
    Red
}
```

And modify your code as follows:

```
        Console.Write("Color To Bet on: ");
        string tempColor = Console.ReadLine();

        bool success = false;

        while (!success)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(tempColor))
            {
                success = false;
                Console.Write("The color can't be null.");
                tempColor = Console.ReadLine();
                continue;
            }

            tempColor = tempColor.First().ToString().ToUpper() + tempColor.Substring(1); //e.g. 'black' will not convert to MyColor.Black
            MyColor selectedColor;
            success = Enum.TryParse<MyColor>(tempColor, out selectedColor);
            if (!success)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You should enter 'Black', 'Green' or 'Red'!");
                tempColor = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Yup, it should be something like this. +10

Comment: You have the colors both in the message and on the enum, you may update the enum and forget to upade the message.

Comment: @Theraot it's easier to have a further deal with enums rather than strings. With string you can get a typo error - e.g. write 'gren' instead of 'green', with enums you can not get this kind of errors

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov yes, I know. I'm not against the enum. But against your string! what if you add Yellow to the enum, but forget to add it (or have a typo as you point out) to the message? The message should come from the enum. Edit. an exercise for the reader, I guess :P

Comment: @Theraot I think, it should be author's decision. Enum can contain value for debug or for extended functionality, about what simple user should not know. In this case usage of direct access to values (`Enum.GetNames()`) will cause producing of unuseful code for excluding some values

Comment: @MikhailNeofitov Agreed. In fact you made think of the case of localization. *Sigh* I miss the simpler times when I didn't care for such things where writing a program. Let it be author's decision.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring your code for a moment... you can check if a variable has some value. With the magic of the `if` statement:

```
if (tempColor == "Red")
{
    // Do red stuff
}
```

You may also be interested in the `switch` statement which may allow you to handle multiple values:

```
switch (tempColor)
{
    case "Black":
        // Do black stuff
        break;
    case "Blue":
        // Do blue stuff
        break;
    case "Red":
        // Do red stuff
        break;
}
```

Or even combine them:

```
switch (tempColor)
{
    case "Black":
    case "Blue":
        // Do black or blue stuff
        break;
    case "Red":
        // Do red stuff
        break;
}
```

---

Now, your code:

```
Console.Write("Color To Bet on: ");
string tempColor = Console.ReadLine();

while (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tempColor))
{
    Console.Write("The color can't be null.");
    tempColor = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
}
```

You probably want that "Color to Bet on" to be said before each input, so:

```
Console.Write("Color To Bet on: ");
string tempColor = Console.ReadLine();

while (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tempColor))
{
    Console.Write("The color can't be null.");
    Console.Write("Color To Bet on: ");
    tempColor = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
}
```

And you problably want that "The color can't be null." to be after the input, and also to read only once^1 so:

```
while(true)
{
    Console.Write("Color To Bet on: ");
    string tempColor = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tempColor))
    {
        Console.Write("The color can't be null.");
        continue;
    }
    break;
}
```

^1: Why? it is more maintanable, look at your code, you forgot to put `ToLower` on the first call. You silly, repeating yourself.

And now you can add your conditional:

```
while(true)
{
    Console.Write("Color To Bet on: ");
    string tempColor = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tempColor))
    {
        Console.Write("The color can't be null.");
        continue;
    }
    if (tempColor != "black" && tempColor != "blue"  && tempColor != "red")
    {
        Console.Write("The color must be Black, Blue or Red");
        continue;
    }
    break;    
}
```

As others that decided to type less than me has pointed out, you can use an array to hold these values.

```
string[] colors = {"black", "green", "red"};
// ...
while(true)
{
    Console.Write("Color To Bet on: ");
    string tempColor = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tempColor))
    {
        Console.Write("The color can't be null.");
        continue;
    }
    if (!colors.Contains(tempColor))
    {
        Console.Write("The color must be Black, Blue or Red");
        continue;
    }
    break;    
}
```

Wait, there is a problem with the code. It still says "Black, Blue or Red" on the message, what if you decide to add a new color to the array and forget to add it to the message? Those texts should appear only once. Also, the user should be notified of what are the valid options before hand.

```
string[] colors = {"black", "green", "red"};
// ...
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The colors are: " + string.Join(",", colors));
    Console.Write("Color To Bet on: ");
    string tempColor = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tempColor))
    {
        Console.Write("The color can't be null.");
        continue;
    }
    if (!colors.Contains(tempColor))
    {
        Console.Write("The color is not valid");
        continue;
    }
    break;    
}
```

You really don't need the first conditional. There is no null or whitespace on the array:

```
string[] colors = {"black", "green", "red"};
// ...
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The colors are: " + string.Join(",", colors));
    Console.Write("Color To Bet on: ");
    string tempColor = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    if (!colors.Contains(tempColor))
    {
        Console.Write("The color is not valid");
        continue;
    }
    break;    
}
```

The conditional we have here has a negation, let's reverse it:

```
string[] colors = {"black", "green", "red"};
// ...
while(true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("The colors are: " + string.Join(",", colors));
    Console.Write("Color To Bet on: ");
    string tempColor = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
    if (colors.Contains(tempColor))
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Hmmm... that can be simplified futher:

```
string[] colors = {"black", "green", "red"};
// ...
string tempColor;
do
{
    Console.WriteLine("The colors are: " + string.Join(",", colors));
    Console.Write("Color To Bet on: ");
    tempColor = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
} while (!colors.Contains(tempColor));
```

---

Addendum: it may be worth noting that given that the set of inputs is fixed, you may assign numbers to them and have the user choose one by number. Other options include making an interactive menu (yes, in console) or supporting autocompleting text... but I would bet you don't care for that.

Answer (score 1):

Extending on *npintis* answer I would like to add the possibility of selecting the color option from a list (like a GUI):

```
    var options = string.Format("Choose between colors:{0}1. Black{0}2. Green{0}3. Red{0} 4. Quit", Environment.NewLine);

    var selection = char.MinValue;
    while (!char.IsDigit(selection))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(options);
        selection = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        Console.Clear();
    }

    int choice = int.Parse(selection.ToString());

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            Console.WriteLine("Black");
            break;
        case 2:
            Console.WriteLine("Green");
            break;
        case 3:
            Console.WriteLine("Red");
            break;
        case 4:
            break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<string> validColors = new List<string>() { "red", "blue", "green" };
  string tempColor = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
  if (validColors.Contains(tempColor))
    {
        //proceed with success code
    }
  else
    {
        // show invalid option
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be adding a strings table with the colors you want, and then checking if it contains the string that the user entered.

```
string[] colors = {"black", "green", "red"};
if (colors.Contains(tempColor.ToLower())) //dosomething
else //dosomething
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
        string[] colours = { "green", "black", "red" };

        Console.Write("Color To Bet on: ");
        string tempColor = Console.ReadLine();

        while (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(tempColor))
        {
            Console.Write("The color can't be null.");
            tempColor = Console.ReadLine().ToLower();
        }

        var result = Array.Exists(colours, element => element == tempColor);
```

Comment: Ideologically it is copy of npinti's answer

Comment: This won't work, if I enter Yellow I won't be asked to enter a valid color.